# My method to extract fuzzy matched terms is crashing when the number of possible matches is large , how can I prevent this?

Tags: java, lucene

***Using Lucene 8.6.3, see the end of this post for how to run an example***

I need to get a list of indexed words which match a fuzzy search expression, and my code is fine for small numbers of matches but throws an exception when the fuzzy term potentially matches too many words. It's possible that I am using the wrong technique, or that my implementation needs some defensive code somewhere.

The query is read as a text query:

`text:sle~1`

and it returns the correct number of matches from the index, through this code:

```
IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(Paths.get(index)));
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
Map<String, Analyzer> analyzerPerField = new HashMap<String, Analyzer>();
analyzerPerField.put("version", new VersionAnalyzer());
PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper analyzerWrapper = new PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper(new TechAnalyzer(), analyzerPerField);

QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(field, analyzerWrapper);
parser.setDefaultOperator(QueryParserBase.AND_OPERATOR);

Query query = parser.parse(line);  // line read earlier from input stream

int max = reader.numDocs();
TopDocs results = searcher.search(query, max);
ScoreDoc[] hits = results.scoreDocs;

int numTotalHits = Math.toIntExact(results.totalHits.value);
HashSet<String> matchedWords = new HashSet<String>();

int end = Math.min(numTotalHits, max);
for (int i = 0; i < end; i++) {
    saveMatchedWords(query, searcher, hits[i].doc, matchedWords, false);
}
```

The method which captures the matching fuzzy terms is here:

```
private static void saveMatchedWords(Query query, IndexSearcher searcher, int docId, HashSet<String> matchedWords, boolean fuzzy) throws IOException {
    boolean inFuzzy = fuzzy;
    if (query instanceof FuzzyQuery)
        inFuzzy = true;
    if (query instanceof TermQuery) {
        if (inFuzzy && searcher.explain(query, docId).isMatch())
            matchedWords.add(((TermQuery) query).getTerm().toString().split(":")[1]);
    }
    else if (query instanceof BooleanQuery) {
        for (BooleanClause clause : (BooleanQuery) query) {
            saveMatchedWords(clause.getQuery(), searcher, docId, matchedWords, inFuzzy);
        }
    }
    else if (query instanceof MultiTermQuery) {
        ((MultiTermQuery) query).setRewriteMethod(MultiTermQuery.SCORING_BOOLEAN_REWRITE);
        saveMatchedWords(query.rewrite(searcher.getIndexReader()), searcher, docId, matchedWords, inFuzzy);
    }
    else if (query instanceof BoostQuery) {
        saveMatchedWords(((BoostQuery) query).getQuery(), searcher, docId, matchedWords, inFuzzy);
    }
}
```

When I run fuzzy searches like `sle~1` the query returns 165 matching documents, and the matchedWords set contains 13 words (in this case, "sale, see, sole, ...").

The problem comes when the fuzzy term matches too many words. I am not sure what the cutoff is, but the largest set of matchedWords I have seen without an exception contained 78 words.

In this example, if we change the fuzzy term to `sle~` (i.e. a distance of 2) then the query executes and returns 422 matching documents, but the saveMatchedWords call throws an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: boost must be a positive float, got -1.0
    at org.apache.lucene.search.BoostQuery.<init>(BoostQuery.java:44)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.ScoringRewrite$1.addClause(ScoringRewrite.java:69)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.ScoringRewrite$1.addClause(ScoringRewrite.java:54)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.ScoringRewrite.rewrite(ScoringRewrite.java:117)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.MultiTermQuery.rewrite(MultiTermQuery.java:313)
    at myDemo.SearchIndex.saveMatchedWords(SearchIndex.java:262)
    at myDemo.SearchIndex.saveMatchedWords(SearchIndex.java:247)
```

I think the error it encounters is misleading, because if it was a problem in how I am extracting the terms then it wouldn't only happen when the number of terms climbs to 80 or more. More likely something somewhere is overflowing, but I'm not sure what.

The example I've given is a bit artificial because searching for such a short term with fuzzy distance 2 is practically useless, but it has revealed that my code is not nearly robust enough as it stands.

Can anybody offer some pointers here that might help?

Cheers
T

***Edit:***

I have set up a small Ant application which illustrates this behaviour.
Download the zipped archive and unzip it into a directory called "mydemo".

(That download is approx 5MB because it includes the three Lucene libraries I have used. If you prefer to use your own Lucene, then there is a smaller zip (230KB), but you will have to modify the build appropriately).

I'm assuming you have Ant, but if not, it should be straightforward to figure out what to do from looking at the targets in `build.xml`.

1. From the "mydemo" folder, type "ant index" which builds the index from the supplied data files (which are just long lists of words).
2. Next type "ant search". This queries the index with the search text "sle~1", and it finds 8 matching files, listing their paths in data/query.out, with 18 fuzzy matched words which are listed in data/query.out.matches.
3. Now edit the file data/query.in, remove the final 1, and save the file. The search text is now "sle~", which will match far more words. In the mydemo folder, type "ant search" again.
4. You should see that the query now matches 12 files, but the code which stores the matched words throws the exception.

***Edit 2:***

This has been an interesting exercise... I have found that the exception is happening because the Queryparser has (correctly) parsed the input into a FuzzyQuery, and that the query.rewrite() called in my `saveMatchedWords` method has attempted to rewrite this as an N-term Boolean query where N is not the number of matches in the document, but the number of matches in the entire index. For a distance=2 fuzzy match this is potentially a very large number indeed.

I tested `BooleanQuery.setMaxClauseCount(num)` with various values to see if increasing the limit fixed the problem, but even with values greater than the total number of indexed terms I still got the exception. So something is overflowing, but probably not the maximum number of Boolean clauses.

However, because this code is iterating over the total number of potential matched terms once for every single matched document, it really isn't a suitable technique for acquiring the fuzzy matching terms, even though it seems to work when the numbers it is dealing with are relatively small. If it doesn't scale, it isn't going to meet the need.

Back to the drawing board.

***Edit 3:***

I have now removed the download links (as the files are no longer available at the url I provided).

Comment: What version of Lucene are you using?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to provide a [mre] which still exhibits this problem, and which we can run for ourselves? For example, can you use one field with the Standard Analyzer (instead of whatever `VersionAnalyzer` and `Tech Analyzer` are doing)? Can you simplify `saveMatchedWords` so it does not need those `if`/`else` checks? Can you provide suitable inputs to help us to recreate the problem? Someone may recognize the problem and "just know" the answer - but otherwise a MRE would be helpful.

Comment: I'll try to produce a simplified example using the standard analyzer tomorrow.

Comment: Example now provided.